# Pictures overlapping during animation. Any ideas how to fix?

Tags: animation, pictures

I'm making a Powerpoint slideshow, and I wanted to make an effect of pictures spinning and growing, and overlapping each other. The problem is the first picture will cover the second picture instead of vice versa, so you only see the first picture. Any ideas? The send to front/forward didn't help. I use two emphasis animations to achieve this- spin, and grow/shrink.
Thanks in advance!